# how to add text before the animation flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and creating an onboard screen. I want to add text before the animation. how can I do that? appreciate your help on this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
    
    class IntroPageOne extends StatelessWidget {
      const IntroPageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Center(
                    child: Lottie.network('https://assets5.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_u5nd9awf.json'),
                
        ),
    
    
            ],
          ),
    
        );
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
body: Center(

```
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("ghdwg"),
        Lottie.network('https://assets8.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_xkxecivz.json'),
      ],
    ),

  ),
);
```